# Why does dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier cause my whole app to crash/hang?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've read all the relevant other questions on this topic and tried the fixes, none of which have worked. My app crashes/hangs to the extent that I have to force quit Xcode in order to restart working, when dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: is called.

It makes no difference if I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, or dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: , and I HAVE set the class with registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: , as you can see in the code below.

Registering the class in my ViewController:

```
@implementation LWSFlavourMatchesViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _flavourMatchesView = [LWSFlavourMatchesView     flavourMatchesViewWithDataSource:self.flavourMatchesDataSource andDelegate:self.flavourMatchesDelegate];
    self.tableView = _flavourMatchesView;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"flavourCell"];
}
```

And trying to dequeue cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath in my dataSource:

```
@implementation LWSFlavourMatchesDataSource

// other methods...

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *flavourCellIdentifier = @"flavourCell";
    NSString *currentSelectedFlavour = [self.flavourWheel selectedFlavour];
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:flavourCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(tableViewCell == nil)
    {
        tableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc ]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:flavourCellIdentifier];
    }
   [tableViewCell.textLabel setText: currentSelectedFlavour];
    return tableViewCell;
//    return [UITableViewCell new];
}
```

If I remove all other code but un-comment out `return [UITableViewCell new];` then the app does not crash. What is it about my dequeuing that is causing this problem?!

Comment: Can you post your crash log?

Comment: Is the tableView returned in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method the same table view as self.tableView? I know if you are using a search bar the tableview that it sends to this method is actually a different instance that will not have the cell registered.

Comment: I can't post a crash log, because the whole thing hangs indefinitely without actually stopping, and I have to kill Xcode in order to stop it running as even killing the simulator doesn't work.

Comment: How would I know which tableView is being passed in? I only have one tableView in my app, I would have thought it was this one?

Comment: *think* it's ios 6. How do I check for sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your tableview delegate. You do not need to check if the cell is nil because you registered the class with `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"flavourCell"];`.

I made your cellIdentifier static. But to remove the duplication on the registerClass function may you make a `#define REUSE_IDENTIFIER @"flavourCell"`.

If this is still slow, than is the `[self.flavourWheel selectedFlavour];` the cause. Check out the instruments tutorial for performance improvements: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *flavourCellIdentifier = @"flavourCell";
    NSString *currentSelectedFlavour = [self.flavourWheel selectedFlavour];
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:flavourCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableViewCell.textLabel setText: currentSelectedFlavour];
    return tableViewCell;
}
```

Comment: You are in fact very right about it being the FlavourWheel method. That is in where the problem lies... I am an idiot who cannot read a debugger. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try removing the class registration:
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"flavourCell"];

You shouldn't need to register the class if you are instantiating a generic UITableViewCell class cell from a storyboard

Comment: It crashed before I added the registration, and it still crashes if I remove it. I'm not using storyboards, doing everything programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Another cause for this error can be-

invalid nib registered for identifier (Cell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UICollectionReusableView instance

I had a UIView in my xib instead of a collectionViewCell. Of course, if you have multiple top level objects in the .xib, the same crash will show. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take care that if your cell is an object in a XIB, and you are using something like :

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"cell_class_name" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell_reuse_name"];
```

to register the cell, be sure the identifier in the attributes inspector in Interface Builder is correct, in this case @"cell_reuse_name".

If the identifier isn't the same, you may be stuck with an odd situation where creating new cells from the nib each time, i.e.

```
NSArray *objects = [bundle loadNibNamed:@"cell_nib_name"
                                  owner:nil
                                options:nil];
cell = (UITableViewCell *)[objects safeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

seems to work fine, but trying to use

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_reuse_name"];
```

crashes.

In practice it's often easiest to use the same name for the XIB, custom class, and reuse identifier.  Then if there are issues, you can just make sure they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had completely different issue. Mismatch between String/XIB based localization. It did help to enable/disable+remove unneeded localizations.

Try this:

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NIB_NAME" owner:self options:nil];
```

If it hangs, there's something wrong with your XIB (like in my case).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"flavourCellIdentifier"]; }
```